# Does $\cup A \subseteq \cup B$ imply $A \subseteq B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering if you could help me with a very basic set theory proof. New to it and somehow seem to wander down every possible dead end when left to my own devices Re. trying to approach proofs  .. any help would be very much appreciated!

- Does ∪A ⊆ ∪B imply A ⊆ B?

Union Axiom:

∪A x:∋y, x ∈ y & y ∈ A

∪B z:∋z, x ∈ z & z ∈ B

If A ⊆ B then ∀x (x ∈ A → x ∈ B)

It doesn't necessarily follow from x ∈ y that x ∈ z

Therefore it doesn't necessarily follow from x ∈ ∪A that x ∈ ∪B?

Comment: Saying "it doesn't necessarily follow" sounds like an intuitive statement rather than a proof.  The statement you are trying to prove has implicit universal quantifiers ("for all $A$, $B$, if $P(A,B)$ holds then $Q(A,B)$ holds") so disproving it amounts to showing that there is some pair of $A$, $B$ for which the implication is false: $P(A,B)$ holds but $Q(A,B)$ fails.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Comment: $\cup A$ is not a well-formed expression; therefore it doesn't mean anything. We have $A\cup B$ and for a family $(A)_{\iota\in I} A_\iota$ we have $\cup_{\iota\in I} A_\iota$.

Comment: Duly noted, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $A=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ and let $B=\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$.

Comment: Thankyou Andre!

So in that case ...

Is ∪A ⊆ ∪B the same as ∪ (A ⊆ B)?

In which case ∪ (A ⊆ B) would be {1, 4}

And the answer would be yes?

Comment: The answer is no, the implication need not hold, the above example is a counterexample to the assertion. For we have $\bigcup A=\bigcup B=\{1,2,3,4\}$ but it is not true that $A\subseteq B$. There is no such thing as $\bigcup(A\subseteq B)$.

Comment: Thankyou again Andre! Do you mind telling me how you made the move from ∪A ⊆ ∪B to ∪A = ∪B?

Comment: I happened to choose an example where that happens. For an example where it doesn't, let $A=\{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$ and $B=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$. With Axiom of Union, of are dealing with sets of sets. You can think of a set as a plastic bag. If it is a set of sets, then it is a plastic bag which contains other plastic bags. If $X$ is such a set (bag of bags) then $\bigcup X$ can be visualized as taking the plastic bags that are the elements of $X$, and emptying them all into a new bag. The set $\bigcup X$ is that new bag.

Comment: So ∪A = {1, 2} and ∪B = {1, 3}?

Comment: Thankyou for the analogy too by the way - helpful

Comment: In the example I gave in the comment, $\bigcup A$ is indeed $\{1,2\}$. But $\bigcup B=\{1,2,3\}$. To find $\bigcup B$, we removed the inner braces (plastic bags) and $1,2,2,3$ spilled out. But we only mention $2$ once.

Comment: I had a good tutorial this morning! This correspondence has been most helpful :-) Thankyou again

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Let $A = \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Thankyou Trevor! Alas have been doing my blind alley thing for a while :/ - A = {∅}, B = {{∅}}

Comment: @Stumpedphilosopher Oh, that works too.  I was thinking of $B = \emptyset$.  Now that I think about it, any $B$ with $\emptyset \notin B$ will (together with $A = \{\emptyset\}$) give a counterexample.

Comment: I understand how yours is a counterexample but not mine? :/               I thought - A = {∅}, B = {{∅}}. So ∪A = ∅ (is that correct?) and ∪B = {∅}? So ∪A ⊆ UB but would it not still follow that A ⊆ B, i.e.  {∅} ⊆ {{∅}}?

Comment: @Stumpedphilosopher You are correct up to the point where you say that $\{\emptyset\} \subseteq \{\{\emptyset\}\}$.  The set $\emptyset$ is an element of the left hand side but not of the right hand side.

Comment: I understand! :-) Thankyou again